# AWS EC2: How to GENERATE a new key pair (.pem file) for an Instance?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-key, pem

I have Linux instance on EC2 and i lost the ".pem" file. So now i can NOT access to my instance through SSH anymore from my terminal.

- How do i regenerate the ".pem" file from AWS EC2 panel?

Comment: No way, if the PEM contained your private key. This is what was supposed to be your most guarded secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regenerating the private key should be impossible. If not, that is a security breach.

Comment: Then How to copy that instance to anoter?

Comment: Adi is right. You can not regenerate it but you can access your instance. Please look at solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906906/generate-pem-file-for-ec2-instance-at-amazon