# generate pem File for EC2 Instance at Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

For our production systems we are running Amazon EC2 Instances.
The colleague responsible (say call him Joe) for that has left the company.

Now we want to have `ssh` access to our instance.

He left us both his private and his public key file.

```
id_dsa
id_dsa.pub
```

In the backend we can see, that the key "joe" is assigned to the runnning instance and that ssh access is done by the following command:

```
ssh -i "joe.pem" ec2-user@11.22.11.123
```

How can we generate a `.pem` file? Or more generally speaking, what needs to be done in order to get ssh access?

Do we need Certificates from Amazon? If so, how?

Comment: You don't "generate" a pem file for an already-running running instance.  You generate it *before* launching the first instance that uses it, and you only have that one single opportunity to download it.  If you lose it, there is no way to recover it, and the instance has to be stopped, the root drive detached, and a new key added, reattach, and reboot.  It would not be much of a security mechanism, otherwise.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 22):

For creating New Pem key:

Go to `EC2 Dashboard` `>` `Key Pair` `>` `Create Key Pair`

This will download `.pem key` file for you.

For SSH access:

1. Extract the public key from is using:

   ```bash
   chmod 400 /path_to_key/key.pem
   ssh-keygen -y -f /path_to_key/key.pem
   ```
2. Add this under the existing public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the instance.
3. You can use new pem key to connect to the instance using `ssh -i "file.pem" ubuntu@ip`

Comment: Just strange, I don't think this is so simple as you explained.

Comment: can i download existing key pairs?

Comment: how to attach this new .pem file to existing ec2 instance @animesh

Answer (score 11):

**Accessing new instances**

Key Pairs are used to grant access to a newly-launched Amazon EC2 instance when using a standard Amazon Machine Image (AMI) supplied by Amazon. (AMIs from other locations may have their own method of logging-in.)

When the instance is launched, a key pair is specified. The EC2 service will then copy the public half of the key pair to `/home/ec2-user.ssh/authorized_keys` (path may vary depending upon AMI chosen).

Then, to connect to the instance, use the private half of the key pair, exactly like you showed:

```
ssh -i joe.pem ec2-user@11.22.11.123
```

(The `ec2-user` login is used for Amazon Linux instances. Ubuntu uses `ubuntu` as the username.)

The name of the key pair to use is shown in the information section of the EC2 instance in the management console:

[image: Key pair in console]

Once an instance has been accessed, it is recommended to **change the key pair in use**, create new users and generally take ownership of the security of the instance. Follow the standard security practices of your organization rather than relying on the key pair used when the instance was launched.

**Accessing existing instances**

For your particular situation, the instances have already been launched and the `ssh` key pair that grants access might (or might not!) be the one used when the instance was first launched.

You also mentioned that you can see that they key `joe` is associated with the instance. In that case, you should try to find `joe.pem` and login to the instance. If you can't find that file, try using the `id_dsa` file instead.

If none of this works, then the problem is one of two things:

- You don't have the key pair that was used when the instance was launched, or
- The key pair on the instance itself has been changed (as per security recommendations)

The bottom line is that, without the key pair, you cannot `ssh` into the instance.

**Recovering access**

Worst case, if you can't `ssh` to the instance, you can still fix things. The general steps are:

- **Stop** the instance (let's call it Instance A)
- **Detach** the boot volume (let's call it Volume A)
- **Start** a new instance, or select an existing instance (let's call it Instance B)
- **Attach** Volume A to Instance B
- **Login** to Instance B and **copy** a new public key pair to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on Volume A
- **Unmount** and **detach** Volume A from Instance B
- **Attach** Volume A to Instance A
- **Start** Instance A

You should now be able to `ssh` into the Instance.

Some references:

- [Connecting to Your Linux Instance Using SSH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)
- [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)

Comment: I forgot to give a feed back ... the step-by-step how to above help me. I was able to get SSH access. Thanks a lot. If somebody is in the same situation. Please take care of the correct mount points. The mount points are shown in Javascript PopUps.

Comment: This worked for me. Please remember to create Instance B in same region that of Instance A otherwise you can not attach volume A to Instance B.